# Open an image from command-line maximized and on second monitor?

Tags: macos, command-line

Is it possible to open an image from command-line maximized (but ideally not enlarged) and on the secondary monitor (if it's plugged in)?

Comment: This is going to depend on your settings in Mission Control for Desktops & Spaces, and the Desktop options for whatever app you're using to open them.